# Why $V^{\pi^*}(s) = \max_{a \in A}Q^{\pi^*}(s,a),\forall s \in S$ in reinforcement learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, proofs, bellman-equations

In some RL notes, I encountered the following equation, which I am trying to prove:
$$
V^{\pi^*}(s) = \max_{a \in A}Q^{\pi^*}(s, a),\forall s \in S
$$

Here is my attemption:

Firstly, I only need to prove "$\geq$" as "$\leq$" is obvious.

Suppose that $\exists S_0 \subset S$ such that $\forall s_0 \in S_0,V^{\pi^*}(s_0) < \max_{a \in A}Q^{\pi^*}(s_0, a)$.(W.L.G, soppose there is only single state $s_0 \in S_0$), i want to construct a new policy $\pi_{\text{new}}$ to derive the contradiction to $V^{\pi^*}(s) \geq V^{\pi}(s), \forall s \in S$ and all policy $\pi$.

I'm trying to create the following policy:

$$\pi_{\text{new}}(a\vert s)=\begin{cases}
1& s=s_0,a=\text{argmax}_{a\in A}Q^{\pi^*}(s_0,a)\\
0& s=s_0, a\neq \text{argmax}_{a\in A}Q^{\pi^*}(s_0,a) \\
\pi^*(a\vert s)& s \in S - s_0
\end{cases}
$$

Next, I want to show
$$
V^{\pi_{\text{new}}}(s_0) = \max_{a\in A}Q^{\pi^*}(s_0, a)
$$
And thus $V^{\pi_{\text{new}}}(s_0) > V^{\pi^*}(s_0)$ to get contradiction. But when I derived it, I encountered some trouble as follow:
$$
V^{\pi_{\text{new}}}(s_0) = \sum_{a \in A}\pi_{\text{new}}(a \vert s_0)Q^{\pi_{\text{new}}}(s_0, a) = Q^{\pi_{\text{new}}}(s_0, \text{argmax}_{a\in A}Q^{\pi^*}(s_0, a)) \overset{?}{=} \max_{a \in A}Q^{\pi^*}(s_0, a)
$$

I guess the last equation holds, but I can't find a way to prove it. Because the policy changed. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you try to prove that there always exist greedy optimal policies. The proof is nontrivial. Here is an outline.

1. Bellman optimality equation (matrix-vector form)

$$v=\max_\pi (r_\pi+\gamma P_\pi v)$$

The solution $v^*$ to this equation is the optimal state value. The solution always exists and is unique. This can be implied by the Contraction Mapping Theorem.

2. When $v^*$ is solved (by for example value iteration), then we can substitute it into the right-hand side of the above equation, and then solve the RHS to obtain a policy $\pi^*$:
   $$\pi^*=\arg\max_\pi (r_\pi+\gamma P_\pi v^*)$$
   This policy is an optimal policy and there always exists a greedy optimal policy.
3. Since $\pi^*$ is greedy, then the definition of state value implies that for any $s$
   $$v_{\pi^*}(s)=\sum_a \pi^*(a|s) q_{\pi^*}(s,a)=\max_a q_{\pi^*}(s,a)$$

This is just an outline. It is impossible to post all the details here. You can check [this book](https://github.com/MathFoundationRL/Book-Mathmatical-Foundation-of-Reinforcement-Learning) Chapter 3: Bellman optimality equation.

Answer (score 0):

So, we've got these Bellman equations for optimal $V^*$ and $Q^*$:
$$ V^*(s) = \max_a\left[R(s,a) + \gamma \sum_{s'}T(s',s,a)V^*(s')\right]\qquad (1)$$
$$Q^*(s,a) = R(s,a) + \gamma \sum_{s'}T(s',s,a)\max_{a'}Q^*(s',a')\qquad (2)$$
Taking $\max_a$ over $(2)$:
$$\max_a Q^*(s,a) = \max_a\left[R(s,a) + \gamma \sum_{s'}T(s',s,a)\max_{a'}Q^*(s',a')\right]$$
We see that this is equivalent to $(1)$ if we denote $V^*(s) = \max_aQ^*(s,a)$.